# Building an Internet Explorer Extension/Add-On?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, add-in

I would like to build a browser extension for IE 7/8. I would like to do it using .NET. Do you know of any resources or tutorials that I could reference to do this? I haven't found much.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/developing-addons.php) on how to do it in VB. [More Info Here](http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/index.php)

Comment: I saw that... it looks to be a commercial product though. I was hoping to find something I could just get going on, even if I had to touch COM programming.

Comment: I found this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SpicIE I would love to read about others experiences.

Comment: A nice article to go with SpiceIE: http://hatim.indexdev.net/2009/04/13/building-a-twitter-client-as-an-internet-explorer-add-on-using-spicie/

Comment: This is a good resource to start with: [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Issuewithbandobjects.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Issuewithbandobjects.aspx)

Comment: [SpicIE - Simple Plug-In Creator for Internet Explorer](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SpicIE)

Comment: I have made a completely working solution for this, in another answer here in StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004#5740004

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same question that was asked two years later has the necessary answer. Everyone should refer to this question now:
[How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions)

Answer (score 11):

JP,

One of the main issues that makes IE extensions hard to develop is the need to develop with C, or .NET.

On the other side, FF and Chrome use (to some extent) JS, which is easier, and has a much lower entrance barrier (How many C "web developers" do you know?).

This is one of the issues / obstacle [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com) is here to solve.
You can create your first IE plugin within minutes. It will save you a lot of research and development time, and you can write your code with Javascript.

On top of that, if you plan this plugin/extension to also work for browsers other than IE then you can develop a cross browser extension once, using an extensive unified API, and we will make it work for Chrome and Firefox.

Chrome and Firefox each one gets a a native extension file (CRX and XPI respectively) while IE a special EXE engine to run your app.

(Disclaimer: I'm a co-founder of Crossrider)

Comment: Why cross rider is shutting down ? Whats the alternative please guide