# Create an IE plugin (aside from Spicie, Add-In Express)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, plugins

Aside from SPICIE and Add-in express IE plugin creator, is there any other out there?

SPICIE, seems good but

Thanks

Comment: Please do not write production-level add-ons in .NET. It's bad for performance and bad for reliability.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Customizing IE for developers](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776819.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I have once answered a question on how to make an IE 8 add-in purely in C#.

Take a look: [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004#5740004)