# Making IE9 Extension button pulse

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am wanting to make an IE9 extension where I add an icon to the toolbar.

When I detect a given element on the page (lets say flash content) I want the icon to become enabled and have its color pulse (or some other slight animation that draws the users attention).

[How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions)

I'm currently using the above as a reference, given that how would I do this?

Comment: A simple browser toolbar button control cannot do this. It's not possible to do this unless you have a toolbar (and even with a toolbar, the performance implications are generally pretty bleak). .

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Is it simile enough to have it as a toolbar button control and have it has one icon when the element isn't on the page (i.e. grayed out) and enabled when it is (i.e. the colored version of the icon)? Also from a performance perspective what is the best way to detect elements on a page (i.e. if there is any video)?