# Deploying IE9 extension

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm looking at developing an IE9 extension (using the following as a reference [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions)) and I'm wondering how I am going to deploy it.

Both Firefox and Chrome have a "store" where you can browse plugins and then a common packaging mechanism/standard, but I haven't been able to find the same for IE... anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check out the [Internet Explorer Gallery Add-ons](http://www.ieaddons.com/us/addons/default.aspx) page.

Comment: [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/ "WiX")

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the plugin as a COM addon, and add two entries to the registry.  The post you linked to explains how to do both of these things.

You would deploy it as an installer package that does both of these things.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX controls are installed automatically (with user permission, if the administrator has not disabled this).  It's all part of the ActiveX specification, which you can find at Microsoft.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751970(v=vs.85).aspx