# How to create Internet Explorer sidebar extension in C#?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, sidebar

I want to create an IE extension - a **sidebar** ("Explorer bar") looking just like bookmarks/favourites sidebar in IE9, it is supposed to show HTML webpage in it.

I googled for a few hours, read some:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776819.aspx (yikes!),
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753587.aspx,
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/Attach_BHO_with_C_.aspx

and

- [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004)

but I need a sidebar - no windows or message boxes. I'd like to see a simple, basic solution - I'll do the details later.

I've created an extension for FF and Chrome - their Extension Dev Centers are much better than Microsoft's.

Please, tell me what should I do in simple steps. I want to create the IE extension in Visual Studio 2010 and C#. There's no way I'll create it in C++.

**EDIT (2011-10-20):**

I've managed to accomplish the solution in [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004) but:

1. it does not work correctly: the set word does not get highlighted at all,
2. I think that the problem is that I use IE9 not 8,
3. the solution does not tell me how to create a **sidebar** for IE9.

BTW. I Use Visual Studio 2010 Express (Visual C# 2010 Express) - not Professional or Ultimate - I think there's no Start External Program option in Debug tab of the Project.

PLEASE help.

Comment: looks to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions - this features a detailed explanation using VS2010 and C#.

Comment: @Conan: It is, and this kind of work should *only* be done in .NET 4.0 and beyond, because you can load multiple versions of the CLR into the process now.

Comment: Using .NET inside IE should still be avoided for performance reasons.

Comment: @Conan: No, it's not a duplicate - I neeed a **sidebar** not a kind of plugin that changes contents of a webpage.

Comment: I have some experience with Add-In Express: http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/ It's amazing - you can simply start adding functionality, there is no need to bother with low-level implementation details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a perfect working example:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSIEExplorerBar-ba8fe182/view/Reviews

It's very interesting that I couldn't find it with Google...

After downloading just extract the file and open CSIEExplorerBar.sln. Some of the solution's projects cannot be imported into VS 2010 - it's just installer projects, you don't need them to run the BHO.

Go to project's properties and in Build Events tab put this text into "Post-build event command line" (literally):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" /f /i "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /unregister "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"
```

Build the project - you get errors because, as you can see, the second command tries to unregister the BHO but nothing is registered yet. You can re-run the build and you'll get no errors.

Open the IE. Open View Menu, Explorer Bars and click "Image List Explorer Bar" - you should see the explorer bar you've just built!

To allow your BHO showing the HTML page you just need to change the User Control design - add the WebBrowser control and add the URL of the page to show to the control.

**Details**

I've created extensions for Chrome and Firefox. IE extensions are the ones of the worst architecture. The documentation is horrible - it's outdated and mosty for C++ only. Extensions for Chrome and Firefox are HTML/XUL and JavaScript based - almost every web developer can build his/hers own extension in minutes! I think it's much much harder in IE - you have to literally EXPLORE the internet to find any information that is useful about this technology.

As you can read here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776819.aspx - you have to play with magical thing called Registry. It's really the worst thing they could choose to store data about extensions. I still don't know where should I add the information about the author or the version of the BHO. If you do please answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926800/how-to-add-author-name-version-number-description-etc-to-browser-helper-objec

The BHO won't work if it's not signed with a key - IEExplorerBar.snk in this solution. You can add a key in a new project very easily - just open the project properties, "Signing" tab - "Sign the assembly" and add the new key.

The documentation is very very old and nobody does anything about it!

**IMHO Microsoft should redesign and write IE again - it's architecture is outdated, anachronic.**

*Some links*

Adding toolbar buttons to open your explorer bar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#details_explorer

Some information about registry in x64 systems:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa384232%28VS.85%29.aspx

About Interlop namespace (SHDocVw): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.aspx