# Does an Internet Explorer Extension / Add-On run in the same process than IE?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, add-on

I have no experience building IE Extensions. I've found some posts that talk about it ([for example this one looks pretty detailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions)), and I see that I need to read much more about this topic... :-)

But my question is not about how to build one. What I would like to know is: If I finally deploy an IE Extension, built in .NET:

- Would my IE Extension / Add-On run in the same process than Internet Explorer?

I don't know if it would run in some kind of sandbox...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/11/ie8-and-loosely-coupled-ie-lcie.aspx

If in older IE versions, the answer is yes. For IE 8 and above, the answer is usually no.

Comment: Thanks @Lex Li ! Anyway... I've read the article and still having some doubts. It seems to be clear that in IE8 and above, each IE Tab runs in a different process... But I'm not sure if the ActiveX, Add-Ons run in different processes, or if they run in the same process of the tab...

Comment: The best way is to write a simple one and load it in IE, and see where you can find it. No post can tell you all the details more than a debugger such as WinDbg.

Comment: Mmmm..., after reading the link again, I guess that all the Add-Ons run in each tab, separatily, but sharing the tab process. But you are right, the best way to be sure is by testing it with a little sample. Thanks!