# develop extension for internet explorer - a big hurdle in front of beginners 

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, bho, browser-extension

I am a beginner in extension development. I have recently developed a **chrome extension** and now i want to move forward to make same for **internet explorer** . 
 I tried my level best to get any documentation to make **IE Extension** but now i am left with a no. of lousy links and documentation which are not giving my any kind of clear idea such that **how IE Extension works** , **What is its architecture**  or **How to build a simple IE Extension**.
I have already seen this related question [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions)
But it was less explanatory and hard to understand . 
Basically I want to develop an IE Extension using **javascript and IE api or other thing** as i have done in **chrome extension**.
So please guide me or at least provide me some **"hello word"** example for IE Extension.

     :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working with CrossRider API for about 4 month now and to my opinion its very good.
They recently released background code support for IE, and HTTP requests control API so now you can actually implement almost every functionality you want crossbrowsered

You can create you own crossrider based extension and run hello world code very easily.
Just register and clone their hello world app:
http://crossrider.com/apps/14648/ide

[image: Crossrider clone button]

About the antiviruses warnings, We have few warnings with the EXE installer for the IE extension (As any new EXE that you might make, especially if its have BHO DLLS) but they are always keeping eye on this and they remove the warnings very quickly.