# Develop IE extension in VS express 2010?

Tags: internet-explorer, atl, bho, browser-extension

I have already developed some simple extensions for chrome and opera.And da documentation provided by them was so cool that It took abt 1 week to get the things.

But developing IE extension is pretty difficult.NO proper documentation !! MSDN tutorials and developing IE extensions given by alex dint help much!! Moreover,I do have VS express 2010..no ATL available !! Can anyone provide me fine links or documentation for developing HELLO WORLD extension ..

And, is it possible to develop IE extension using JavaScript and HTML as in Opera and Chrome?

Comment: Developing extensions for IE is kind of like designing sunglasses for blind people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATL is COM/ActiveX, and COM/ActiveX is Oh-So-1995, Dude.  I wouldn't recommend going there ;)

You *can* write IE extensions in .Net.  Consequently, you *should* be able to use either/both the C# and/or VB.Net versions of MSVS Express 2010:

- http://msmvps.com/blogs/vcsjones/archive/2010/05/23/writing-a-managed-internet-explorer-extension-part-1.aspx

Finally, there's also a lot of good information in this link:

- [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004#5740004)

Comment: thnx buddy !! it's helpful :)