# Internet Explorer 7+ Addon to control tabs

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, ieaddon

Initial note, I am not a c# programmer, but I have developed addon/extensions for chrome and firefox, and I need a third extension for internet explorer for a work-related project.

I am trying to access the Internet Explorer instance from a BHO extension in IE.  I've been using the following as resources:

- [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004#5740004)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19971/How-to-attach-to-Browser-Helper-Object-BHO-with-C
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/03a8c835-e9e4-405b-8345-6c3d36bc8941 (**need help with this**)

So, I have the basic addon working, and testing it by injecting a javascript alert box when the window is finished loading.

My addon will eventually have to manage two tabs (one acting as a host, the other a slave), and the [last link mentioned](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/03a8c835-e9e4-405b-8345-6c3d36bc8941) deals with it, but it requires HWND handle for the browser, and I'm not sure how to get that.

It looks like it might be under the `WebBrowser` member `.Parent` but I don't know what class I'd need to cast it to get the IE handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to get the handle of any browser or even any process **already** running on the machine, you can use the FindWindow methods within the:

> User32.dll

by including a reference to it within your class in the following way:

```
    // Find by class name and window name
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    // Find window name only
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);
```

and you can call them within your class like following:

```
    public FindMyWindow(string classname, string windowName)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(classname, null);
        // Or do
        hWnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, windowName);
    }
```

You can use

> Spy++

Which comes with Visual Studio 2010 to find the classname if you want.

Comment: I'm not opposed to this, **but** since I'm developing an IE-only plugin, and I know I should be able to get the process HWND that the plugin attaches to, I see your code as a last-resort hack-ish way to do things.  I know there must be a way to get it from the WebBrowser interface, I just don't know how, and I'm not particularly good at c# (I'm actually learning as I go for this project).