# How to run a modern userscript on Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, userscripts, browser-extension

I've found it's pretty easy to take a Greasemonkey-type userscript and turn it into extensions/addons for Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. And of course one can run them natively in Chrome, and simply in Firefox using the Greasemonkey addon.

I'm now exploring whether I can run my userscript on IE at all. I tried the ancient Trixie and the bloatwarish ie7pro, but neither run the script correctly. They partially work, but also appear to reload the script many times on the same page, continually inserting the items that should only appear once.  The oft-mentioned Greasemonkey for IE now appears defunct, its domain name (gm4ie.com) having been parked and full of ads.

I've dug in w/ search a bit, looking for information about how to develop IE extensions (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004#5740004)).  But I've had no luck finding anyone talking about getting a userscript to run inside of an addon.  At the least it looks like javascript might not be available w/in those environments, necessitating a complete rewrite in C#.

Are there any Greasemonkey-type addons I haven't listed above?  Is it possible to convert a javascript userscript into an IE extension?

Comment: why not add some extra tests, like if an element exists then return ..

Comment: Yes, IE uses proprietary API's.  You'll pretty much want-to/have-to rewrite everything from scratch.  It's not worth it.  **However**, if you rewrite your extension using [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com/), they *claim* that it supports all the major browsers.  ... PS: You'll note that there is no "internet-explorer-extension" tag. (hint, hint (and not to create the tag, either))

Comment: This is not off topic. The question is about using a programming language/environment (Greasemonkey) on a new platform (Internet Explorer).

Comment: @Will Why was this closed?

Comment: @Hjulle: Sorry, wrong button.  It's closed because it is a "shopping question", which we actively discourage.  For more information, search for that on [meta].

Comment: FYI The original data of gm4ie is available in the Web Archive - http://web.archive.org/web/20110624002700/http://www.gm4ie.com/

Comment: See, also [Possible to run userscript in IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25059256/331508).