# Possible to run userscript in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, userscripts

I have a custom userscript that I'm running in Chrome and Firefox using Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey.

Is there any way of using this script in IE11? Or is there any plugins for IE11 that does what Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey does?

Answer (score 11):

[*TrixIE WPF4.5*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trixiewpf45/) claims to emulate Greasemonkey on IE11.

Unfortunately, [the original *Trixie* and *IE7Pro*](http://www.pcworld.com/article/184108/use_greasemonkey_scripts_in_ie_safari_and_chrome.html) stopped working around IE8-ish.

Comment: Your sourceforge link is to different project with similar name, that works on IE11 (original TrixIE doesn't)

Answer (score 2):

I use localStorage to make it work, which is supported by IE8 or later.

Steps:

1. Run the following code in IE's developer tool when the current window is in the domain where you want the script to run in:

```js
var scriptName = 'Hello world';
function scriptBody(){
//---userscript starts--->

document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello world!</h1>';

//---userscript ends--->
}
var script = scriptBody.toString()
  .split('//---userscript starts--->')[1]
  .split('//---userscript ends--->')[0];
localStorage.setItem(scriptName, script);
```

2. Create a bookmark and modify the URL into:

```js
javascript:(function(){eval(localStorage.getItem('Hello world'));})()
```

Advantages:

- No additional plugin needed.
- Almost no script text length limit.

Disadvantages:

- Need a user to click on a bookmark to run the script.
- Need a reinstall if a user clears the browser cache.

Comment: This is a very nice solution. I'm glad to be the first to give some credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google Search (I searched  "greasemonkey for IE") yields various alternatives available for other browsers:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey#Equivalents_for_other_browsers

> For Internet Explorer, similar functionality is offered by IE7Pro,[19] Sleipnir,[20] and iMacros.

Comment: That information has been obsolete since IE8. Also, Sleipnir is a browser, not an IE solution and iMacros will work but is not Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey compatible (iMacros has much more power, though).

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler supports modifying the response of http requests.
We can use this feature to load userscript in any browser, include IE8.

This is an example:

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
    if (m_Hide304s && oSession.responseCode == 304) {
        oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
    }
    // match url
    if (oSession.fullUrl == "http://apply.ccopyright.com.cn/goadatadic/getR11List.do") {
        oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
        var script = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\GitHub\\@selpic\\P660_printer\\Printer\\scripts\\form-save-load.js")
        oSession.utilReplaceOnceInResponse("</body>", "<script>"+script+"</script></body>", true);
    }
}
```

doc: [Modifying a Request or Response](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/fiddlerscript/modifyrequestorresponse)

Answer (score -6):

Just open **Developer tools** (press F12) and paste your script to **Console**, and then run it (Ctrl + Enter).

Comment: This is not what a user script is usually used for.