# How to execute js script file in IE console?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a webpage that I can only access from IE (due to LDAP authentication via ActiveX).

When I launch the URL, I'd like to fire a command from the ie console to run a javascript file.
This file should then eg click some buttons on the page within the ie automatically.
Eg by using `document.getElementById(..).click();`

Question: how can I run a local scriptfile from the console? Is that possible at all?
If not, how could I automate some button clicks within the browser itself? (I'm not allowed to execute any selfcompiled scripts in eg a different language due to security restrictions on the machine).

Comment: Im not sure, thats why im posting this as comment, but could you use something like Tampermonkey, maybe [this link](https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?t=1108)

Comment: I could install any plugins in IE itself, but not in the system.

Comment: I found [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059256/possible-to-run-userscript-in-ie11) but im not sure if it´s helpful, tell me.

Comment: copy/paste the script into the console, click on the run button