# Is it possible for a Internent Explorer add-on to affect the script in a web page

Tags: internet-explorer

I've an application where a user has reported an script error, and nothing is displayed in the  page (just a white background is displayed with a error notification in the notification area).

The user is using Internet Explorer 8.0 with some add-ons, and they are not ready to share further details.

The error notification says a script error as given below, but the application does not have reference to the said file (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js), we have our own copy of jQuery-1.5.1 within the site.

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   Trident/4.0; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET
>   CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
>
> Timestamp: Fri, 22 Feb 2013 01:23:08 UTC
>
> Message: Object required
>
> Line: 2
>
> Char: 14776
>
> Code: 0
>
> URI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

So my question is: Is it possible that some third party add-ons is causing the problem.

Note: Welcome down votes

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is possible by way of [Browser Helper Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms976373.aspx). There is a related question [Developing Internet Explorer Extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions) and the code from the accepted answer by [Miguel Angelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195417/miguel-angelo) includes an example of executing a JavaScript prompt and modifying the contents of the page.