# Browser Helper Object that works in IE 10 WIndows 8 64 example

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, internet-explorer-10, bho

I`m struggling with this for a week already. I used this example [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions) and it works flawlessly even in Win 7 64 bit IE 10 but not in Windows 8 64 IE 10.

It loads up correctly but just does nothing, even with a simple `MessageBox` put in `OnDocumentComplete()`. Though I found people on different forums confirming they have made it run, so all I am asking is, just an example that works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

"Register for COM interop" tick box in the Build section of the project properties did the trick. Funny enough any other combination of software and browser works fine without it.