# ATL COM is the only way to develop IE7 or above addons/extensions?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, com, atl

I went through various resources available on internet and found that ATL COM is used to develop addons for IE9 or above. But as per my knowledge this library is very old library.  There must be something new from which IE addons can be developed.

Pl let me know if you have any idea/suggestions.

Comment: ATL isn't all that old, and it's well enough designed for its purpose that it's open to at least some question whether a replacement would be significantly better.

Comment: So there is no other way of creating IE addons as of now. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: ATL isn't old; its seasoned. It has been updated with every release of Visual C++, and several-times-over refreshed since its inception, to the point where MFC now rips off much of its functionality from ATL. Out of the box "click this to make a skeleton IE add-in" functionality is provided via wizards to dev studio, but ultimately its COM at the core, and you could write it in raw C if you were so inclined (and of questionable sanity).

Comment: Well, I would say that ATL is indeed old, but very alive and kicking.

Comment: It is *stable*, unfortunately too often a code word for "dead".  ATL isn't required to write COM code, it is just kinda dumb to not use it.  Available books are excellent and still in print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally COM is language agnostic, so you can use any programming language and libraries that support it.

Also refer to this question: [Developing Internet Explorer Extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions)

Comment: Thanks Sergius!! Is there any difference if i write BHO programme using ATL COM or C# .NET?

Comment: C# requires .NET framework while ATL COM can be built without any dependencies.

Comment: I have seen description of interface of IObjectWithSite interface but could not understand. Pl let me know what is it and how it works in your language.

Comment: Ok. Site is a container where an object is hosted. Using IObjectWithSite a container tells the object that it is its host now. After that the object can interact with its host (it has a pointer to the host).

Comment: Ok.So container site is a IE browser (lets say button/icon on browser) and object is our app which is registered. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I have to place a icon/button on IE browser and on click of it i have to perform some operation. Which option do i need to use :-               1.Shortcut menu extensions

2.Toolbars

3.Explorer Bars

4.Browser Helper Objects

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30249/discussion-between-mukesh-sakre-and-sergius)

Comment: Please provide your response on stackoverflow.com/q/16663603/1513701 @sergius

Comment: @mukesh-sakre: Sorry, forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not necessary to use ATL.  You can certainly create COM-compliant components without the help of ATL.