# Internet Explorer. Interact with IE in real-time, how to?

Tags: internet-explorer

I have web-server(as a part of my gneral application). Also I have FireFox, Chrome and Opera plugins for transfering data between browser and server.
Each plugin realize tool bar button, and menu item in context menu(when user call right click on web-page).

Whitch is the best way to realize that extension for IE?

Comment: this question is totally messy, it's not clear what you are asking at all. Bounty will not help you if you cannot express yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you should create an Addon for Internet Explorer. I don't know exactly what you want achieve but this answer should help you to get through to an implementation of an add-on: [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions). Good Luck