# IE extension - onclick how to call a C# method

Tags: c#, javascript, html, internet-explorer

Can someone please let me know how to call a C# method from onclick event using the example provided by Miguel Angelo in this link? 
[How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions/23523816#23523816)

I have tried the following but it doesn't work. Is it possible to have a javascript run on Onclick and have that call a C# method? I have tried WebMethod, that didn't work either.

Both the following code is in the same .cs file

```
var newText = textNode.data.Replace(m.Value, "< span runat='server'; style='background-color: yellow; cursor: hand;' onclick='OnClientClick'; title='Click for more options.'>" + m.Value + "</span>");
```

c# method

```
protected void OnClientClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Called OnClientClick ");
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Explain what "doesn't work" means. That tells us pretty much nothing about the problem you're encountering.

Comment: I don't get the pop that says "Called OnClientClick" when I click on the text I am targeting on. I have tried calling a javascript instead having an alert on Onclick, that worked, i got the pop. What I want to accomplish is to call the OnClientClick method either through a javascript or directly.

Comment: In the example you are copying from, the `onclick` event handler that is dynamically added by the C# code is still only calling a javascript function.  The example doesn't show calling back into C#.

Comment: that's true, but I want know how to call back in to C# on onclick event. Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? I am new to web development, greatly appreciate with any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not super familiar with C#, but in Java, or PHP, I would create a JavaScript event that would call a separate 'processing' page via AJAX. If you need a response, AJAX can return a structured set of values in the JSON format which you can also parse with JavaScript.

http://html.net/tutorials/javascript/lesson18.php