# IE BHO written in C# 4.0 is working in IE 9 but not working in IE10 on a windows 7 machine

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer, bho

I have written a `BHO` by following " [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions). " and it worked very well for me in `IE8` and `IE9`. But the same is not working in `IE10` and above. Are there any differences between `IE9` and `IE10` in terms of `BHO` code.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though without more information about the problems you're running into with IE10, it's hard to what specific information to point you to.

Here are a couple of links to get you started:

- [Supporting Enhanced protected mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn519894(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [ActiveX control and plugin changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn467847(v=vs.85).aspx) (to Internet Explorer)
- [Plugin and ActiveX support in Windows 8 and Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920753(v=vs.85).aspx)

I can tell you that BHOs written in managed code are not formally supported.  Here are a few links that discuss the problems:

- [IE Blog: Add-on Performance Part 3: Optimizing Add-on Startup Performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/07/add-on-performance-part-3-optimizing-add-on-startup-performance.aspx)
- [MSDN Magazine: In-Process Side-by-Side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx)
- [The Old New Thing: Do not write in-process shell extensions in managed code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx)

(Note that the last link is written by Raymond Chen, one of the smartest guys at Microsoft.  It's not wise to ignore his advice.)

Please do try to isolate the problem into more details.  That makes it much easier to help.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: 32 bit version of BHO is working in IE 10 64 bit machine. But the 64 bit is not working on the same machine

Comment: By "not working" you mean...?  Are there error messages?  Is an object failing to instantiate?  Have you tried tracing the code to see if there's an execution failure?  Perhaps there's an environmental factor that's interfering...?

Comment: No error messages, nothing. It does not load at all. I did not debug this.