# What is the simpliest way to install a BHO

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, plugins, bho

I am not a windows programmer but it seems that I have to do an extension for Internet explorer.

I made a BHO with the help of this thread : [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/how-to-get-started-with-developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004#5740004)

I did it, it "works" with VS's debug mode. Now I want a way to install it on a target machine.

I know there is a lot of thread all over internet but half of it don't work for me and I can't understand the other half. Windows's system programming is not a trivia for me and I really need help on this one. It took like 30 minutes to do the same things on Firefox/Chrome.

Let's consider that I have my extension.dll. What should I do with it ? Where should i register it to make it work in IE ? Am I considering the problem wrong, should I just learn outdated Windows's system for weeks ?

Thanks in advance, I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Compile your extension in `Release` mode
- On the target machine run `regsvr32.exe /s extension.dll` under the administrator privileges

Comment: I am also running into same issue .I have nlogger implemented in BHO.I am able to see logs in visual studio 2015 debug mode running on Windows 10. But when I did these above steps I am not able to see logs . Can you please help me