# Install dll on different machine

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-11

I’ve built an Internet Explorer Browser Helper Object in Visual Studio and verified if works by building it locally with regasm.

This produced a Release .dll file which I tried to build on a different computer with no luck.

Is there an easier way to package all of this or am I missing an important step?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you refer steps below.

- Compile your extension in Release mode On the target machine run
- regsvr32.exe /s extension.dll under the administrator privileges

Reference:

[What is the simpliest way to install a BHO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271534/what-is-the-simpliest-way-to-install-a-bho)