# Script to automatically submit form in any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, login-script

Note: I could not think words for this question to search in Google. That's why asking my question. Please bear with me.

I have internet subscription of `xyz company` and it's login based connection. But what happens is that sometimes login screen reappears and is asking for password. I have already stored user name and password in web page but I have to click on `login` button to relogin again.

Can I have any script written for this login page that whenever internet connection goes and asks for relogin again, script automatically submit form and get connected with internet?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for content scripts. There is no cross-browser way to inject code into a web page, but each major browser has a well documented way to do it:

- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts)
- [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)
- [Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/how-to-get-started-with-developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004#5740004)

Technically you could also write a script that sniffs HTTP requests using a tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and posts form data whenever it detects the page is displayed, but that doesn't seem like a great solution.