# Cannot get BHO working in 64 bit

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, bho

I'm working on IE11 Browser Helper Object. I got it working when I build it in x86. The problem is, I want to use the project on x64 the BHO extension isn't working when it's built on x64.

The extension shows up in the Internet Explorer add-ons screen, but the javascript popup is not showing up.

The DLL is registered using the x64 version of regasm via the Visual Studio command prompt as administrator, with/without the `/codebase` and `/tlb` but without result. The registry key is added successfully in my registry but the BHO is simply not working in IE. I've also tried placing the files in a subfolder of Program Files, but it simply is not working.

When I run my IE in Enhanced Protected Mode the add-on manager shows that my BHO is `incompatible`, but without EPM the IE shows `enabled` even though it's not working.

I'd like to get the BHO working on x64.

I also tried [this 'hello world' BHO project](https://github.com/reinaldo13/ie-bho-extension) but when I change it to build on x64 in stead of x86 the same problem occurs.

Comment: The provided sample works in 64-bit for me. You have to 1) compile x64 2) register using `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe ieextension.dll /codebase` (no need to copy to program files thanks to codebase), 3) make sure main iexplore.exe runs 64-bit, 4) make sure "Enable 64-bit processes for Enhanced Protected Mode" is checked in IE"s Tools/Options/Advanced. FYI I don't have "Enable Enhanced Protected Mode" enable.

Comment: The [ComRegisterFunction] method looks quite broken to me, it only writes the BHO key but fails to write the CLSID keys.  @Simon, how did you get it going?  Did you perhaps do the same thing the CodeProject author might have done and have a version of the code without the [ComRegisterFunction] at first?

Comment: @HansPassant - yes, I forget to say I changed RegisterBHO to `registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid, true);` to be able to write the key, but it's the only change I made. Regasm 64 must be ran as admin (as usual for changes in HKLM) Plus setup IE options as in my previous comments.

Comment: Yuck, and that.  It still baffles me how anybody got this going, I suspect their projects had the "Register for COM interop" checkbox turned on.  But sure, doesn't work in 64-bit mode.  And won't work on another machine.  Afaik, the [ComRegisterFunction] must call RegistrationServices.RegisterAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase) so the CLSID keys are properly written so IE can find the DLL and mscoree.dll can load it.

Comment: @HansPassant - I posted an answer, I think it's mandatory to have both x86 and x64 versions registered for the same CLSID to make IE happy.

Answer (score 4):

It seems it doesn't work for everyone, so, I'll describe what I did to make it work.

1) download the sample project from here: https://github.com/reinaldo13/ie-bho-extension

2) modify `RegisterBHO(...)` method in `BHO.cs`

from:

```
RegistryKey ourKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid);
```

to:

```
  RegistryKey ourKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid, true); //we want to write the registry
```

3) compile the project for **AnyCPU**: Project properties, select AnyCPU for the platform target.

4) create a .bat like this, adapt yo your path, and copy that aside your outputs dll:

```
 "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" ieextension.dll /codebase
 "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" ieextension.dll /codebase
```

This will register the dll for x86 and x64. This is **mandatory** to have both version registered otherwise IE won't like it (it will complain the extension is 'incompatible') because it won't be able to start it depending on your IE settings. Note I suppose you can have two different files for each version but .NET's AnyCPU doesn't need that.

5) run that .bat as admin, here is the output when I do this:

```
"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" ieextension.dll /codebase
Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version 4.7.2046.0
for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.7.2046.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

RegAsm : warning RA0000 : Registering an unsigned assembly with /codebase can cause your assembly to interfere with other applications that may be installed on the same computer. The /codebase switch is intended to be used only with signed assemblies. Please give your assembly a strong name and re-register it.
Types registered successfully
"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" ieextension.dll /codebase
Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version 4.7.2046.0
for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.7.2046.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

RegAsm : warning RA0000 : Registering an unsigned assembly with /codebase can cause your assembly to interfere with other applications that may be installed on the same computer. The /codebase switch is intended to be used only with signed assemblies. Please give your assembly a strong name and re-register it.
Types registered successfully
```

6) run `iexplore.exe`. It may work depending on your settings (displays a "HOLA!!!" messagebox), but anyway, go to menu Tools / Internet Options / Programs / Manage add-ons, this is what I see:

[image]

If the extension is disabled, you should be able to enable it (and restart).

If it doesn't work (by default it shouldn't), make sure you've checked "Enable 64-bit processes for Enhanced Protected Mode*" (needs restart). To me the message is wrong, it should just say "Enable 64-bit processes"...

[image]

Comment: Simon, from the screenshot I see you don't have "Enable Enhanced Protection Mode" ticked. How do you know its using Enhanced Protection Mode? I don't think it is and that is why its working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Regasm.exe (Assembly Registration Tool) [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool)

Check your project settings to compile as 64bit and check IE version as well . and run it in Administrator mode.

Your Code is perfect. just the system settings and compilation configurations are messed up ,

also have a look at this setting 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/enable-64-bit-processes-in-ie-11/212270df-cc35-4e09-89e4-13b9da1bb6a7?auth=1

Hope this will help you out !!