# Issues with strong name BHO c# for IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I am developing a Browser Helper Object in C# for internet explorer. 
This post has been very helpful to me: [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/how-to-get-started-with-developing-internet-explorer-extensions)

One issue I am having though relates to strong naming. I have found how to strong name from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/strong-named-assemblies 
I am able to create a strong name keyfile and register using gacutil and then regasm with no errors. When I launch IE my BHO shows up as enabled, but it doesn't seem like any of the code is actually getting executed. I have spent some time searching online, but I did not see anything helpful regarding how to diagnose the issue. I have two questions: 
1. What steps can I take / what are some things I can look for to see what went wrong / why the BHO code is not getting executed? 
2. If I do not strong-name sign the application, regasm /codebase works fine and my BHO code executes, but I get the warning saying it is not strong named. Based on looking online, it doesn't seem like this would really cause any problems unless there was another application with the exact same name. Is this correct / would it be a valid option to just leave my BHO unsigned? 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: you should ngen and ship both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of your BHO as IE can open 32 bit and 64 bit tabs depending on which security zone the web site is in

Comment: Hi, 
Are you referring to ngen as a way to address the issue I am bringing up or for something separate? I found these two articles and it looks like ngen is mainly for performance purposes? 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clrcodegeneration/2007/09/15/to-ngen-or-not-to-ngen/ 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clrcodegeneration/2010/04/27/ngen-getting-started-with-ngen-in-visual-studio/

And the 32-bit vs. 64-bit compatibility is a separate issue, correct?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003656/cannot-get-bho-working-in-64-bit. you have to register for both 32 bit and 64bit registry too.