# Hello World Internet explorer extension (add-on)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

After I developed chrome extension I want to develop my first Intenet Explorer 11 addon, I wrote a code based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5740004/12550657) answer. When I run the project it looks like I was succeded to create a add-on:

Under Settings-->Manage add-ons I can see my add-on:

[image]

> But how do I show "Hello world" message (I only want to test that the my extension really work even a console.log message)

**What I did:**

1. I opened a class library project (.NET Framework 4.6.1)
2. Added reference to `mshtml` and to `SHDocVw` and to `System.Windows.Forms` (all are built in no need to download)
3. Added class `Interop` and class `IEAddon`.
4. Set build events
5. Set Debug arguments and startin external program

***Here My code:***

**AssemblyInfo.cs:**

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Lib.Test1")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Lib.Test1")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2020")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

**Interop.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Lib.Test1
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("1947599d-eac5-4772-9a65-aa4b70aa2930")]
    public interface IObjectWithSite
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetSite([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]object site);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSite(ref Guid guid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]out IntPtr ppvSite);
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct OLECMDTEXT
    {
        public uint cmdtextf;
        public uint cwActual;
        public uint cwBuf;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
        public char rgwz;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct OLECMD
    {
        public uint cmdID;
        public uint cmdf;
    }

    [ComImport(), ComVisible(true),
    Guid("7fcb81da-7061-47af-b7ad-796badbd9f42"),
    InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IOleCommandTarget
    {

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [PreserveSig]
        int QueryStatus(
            [In] IntPtr pguidCmdGroup,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint cCmds,
            [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref OLECMD prgCmds,
            //This parameter must be IntPtr, as it can be null
            [In, Out] IntPtr pCmdText);

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [PreserveSig]
        int Exec(
            //[In] ref Guid pguidCmdGroup,
            //have to be IntPtr, since null values are unacceptable
            //and null is used as default group!
            [In] IntPtr pguidCmdGroup,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint nCmdID,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint nCmdexecopt,
            [In] IntPtr pvaIn,
            [In, Out] IntPtr pvaOut);
    }
}
```

**IEAddon.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using mshtml;
using SHDocVw;

namespace Lib.Test1
{

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("b908e54f-8c58-4d5d-8762-60d7d675cd39")]
    [ProgId("Test1")]
    public class MyAddon : IObjectWithSite, IOleCommandTarget
    {
        const string DefaultTextToHighlight = "GUID";

        IWebBrowser2 browser;
        private object site;

        #region Highlight Text
        void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
        {
            try
            {
                // @Eric Stob: Thanks for this hint!
                // This was used to prevent this method being executed more than once in IE8... but now it seems to not work anymore.
                //if (pDisp != this.site)
                //    return;
                MessageBox.Show("hello1");
                var document2 = browser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
                var document3 = browser.Document as IHTMLDocument3;

                var window = document2.parentWindow;
                window.execScript(@"function FncAddedByAddon() { alert('Message added by addon.'); }");

                Queue<IHTMLDOMNode> queue = new Queue<IHTMLDOMNode>();
                foreach (IHTMLDOMNode eachChild in document3.childNodes)
                    queue.Enqueue(eachChild);

                while (queue.Count > 0)
                {
                    // replacing desired text with a highlighted version of it
                    var domNode = queue.Dequeue();

                    var textNode = domNode as IHTMLDOMTextNode;
                    if (textNode != null)
                    {
                        if (textNode.data.Contains(TextToHighlight))
                        {
                            var newText = textNode.data.Replace(TextToHighlight, "<span style='background-color: yellow; cursor: hand;' onclick='javascript:FncAddedByAddon()' title='Click to open script based alert window.'>" + TextToHighlight + "</span>");
                            var newNode = document2.createElement("span");
                            newNode.innerHTML = newText;
                            domNode.replaceNode((IHTMLDOMNode)newNode);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // adding children to collection
                        var x = (IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection)(domNode.childNodes);
                        foreach (IHTMLDOMNode eachChild in x)
                        {
                            if (eachChild is mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)
                                continue;
                            if (eachChild is mshtml.IHTMLStyleElement)
                                continue;

                            queue.Enqueue(eachChild);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region Load and Save Data
        static string TextToHighlight = DefaultTextToHighlight;
        public static string RegData = "Software\\test1Extension";

        [DllImport("ieframe.dll")]
        public static extern int IEGetWriteableHKCU(ref IntPtr phKey);

        private static void SaveOptions()
        {
            //File.WriteAllText(@"d:\ieextension-test1B.txt", "aaaaaaaaaa");
            // In IE 7,8,9,(desktop)10 tabs run in Protected Mode
            // which prohibits writes to HKLM, HKCU.
            // Must ask IE for "Writable" registry section pointer
            // which will be something like HKU/S-1-7***/Software/AppDataLow/
            // In "metro" IE 10 mode, tabs run in "Enhanced Protected Mode"
            // where BHOs are not allowed to run, except in edge cases.
            // see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx
            IntPtr phKey = new IntPtr();
            var answer = IEGetWriteableHKCU(ref phKey);
            RegistryKey writeable_registry = RegistryKey.FromHandle(
                new Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle(phKey, true)
            );
            RegistryKey registryKey = writeable_registry.OpenSubKey(RegData, true);

            if (registryKey == null)
                registryKey = writeable_registry.CreateSubKey(RegData);
            registryKey.SetValue("Data", TextToHighlight);

            writeable_registry.Close();
        }
        private static void LoadOptions()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hello2");
            // In IE 7,8,9,(desktop)10 tabs run in Protected Mode
            // which prohibits writes to HKLM, HKCU.
            // Must ask IE for "Writable" registry section pointer
            // which will be something like HKU/S-1-7***/Software/AppDataLow/
            // In "metro" IE 10 mode, tabs run in "Enhanced Protected Mode"
            // where BHOs are not allowed to run, except in edge cases.
            // see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx
            IntPtr phKey = new IntPtr();
            var answer = IEGetWriteableHKCU(ref phKey);
            RegistryKey writeable_registry = RegistryKey.FromHandle( new Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle(phKey, true));
            RegistryKey registryKey = writeable_registry.OpenSubKey(RegData, true);

            if (registryKey == null)
                registryKey = writeable_registry.CreateSubKey(RegData);
            registryKey.SetValue("Data", TextToHighlight);

            if (registryKey == null)
            {
                TextToHighlight = DefaultTextToHighlight;
            }
            else
            {
                TextToHighlight = (string)registryKey.GetValue("Data");
            }
            writeable_registry.Close();
        }
        #endregion

        [Guid("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA")]
        [InterfaceType(1)]
        public interface IServiceProvider
        {
            int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvObject);
        }

        #region Implementation of IObjectWithSite
        int IObjectWithSite.SetSite(object site)
        {
            Debugger.Launch();
#if DEBUG
            //Debugger.Launch();
#endif
            //File.WriteAllText(@"d:\ieextension-test1D.txt", "aaaaaaaaaa");
            this.site = site;

            if (site != null)
            {
                LoadOptions();

                var serviceProv = (IServiceProvider)this.site;
                var guidIWebBrowserApp = Marshal.GenerateGuidForType(typeof(IWebBrowserApp)); // new Guid("0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
                var guidIWebBrowser2 = Marshal.GenerateGuidForType(typeof(IWebBrowser2)); // new Guid("D30C1661-CDAF-11D0-8A3E-00C04FC9E26E");
                IntPtr intPtr;
                serviceProv.QueryService(ref guidIWebBrowserApp, ref guidIWebBrowser2, out intPtr);

                browser = (IWebBrowser2)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(intPtr);

                ((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)browser).DocumentComplete +=
                    new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
            }
            else
            {
                ((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)browser).DocumentComplete -=
                    new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
                browser = null;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        int IObjectWithSite.GetSite(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr ppvSite)
        {
            IntPtr punk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(browser);
            int hr = Marshal.QueryInterface(punk, ref guid, out ppvSite);
            Marshal.Release(punk);
            return hr;
        }
        #endregion
        #region Implementation of IOleCommandTarget
        int IOleCommandTarget.QueryStatus(IntPtr pguidCmdGroup, uint cCmds, ref OLECMD prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        int IOleCommandTarget.Exec(IntPtr pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
        {
            try
            {
                // Accessing the document from the command-bar.
                var document = browser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
                var window = document.parentWindow;
                var result = window.execScript(@"alert('You will now be allowed to configure the text to highlight...');");

                //  var form = new HighlighterOptionsForm();
                // form.InputText = TextToHighlight;
                // if (form.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
                // {
                TextToHighlight = "GUID";
                SaveOptions();
                // }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            return 0;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Registering with regasm
        public static string RegBHO = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";
        public static string RegCmd = "Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Extensions";

        [ComRegisterFunction]
        public static void RegisterBHO(Type type)
        {
            string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");

            // BHO
            {
                RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegBHO, true);
                if (registryKey == null)
                    registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(RegBHO);
                RegistryKey key = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid);
                if (key == null)
                    key = registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid);
                key.SetValue("Alright", 1);
                registryKey.Close();
                key.Close();
            }

            // Command
            {
                RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegCmd, true);
                if (registryKey == null)
                    registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(RegCmd);
                RegistryKey key = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid);
                if (key == null)
                    key = registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid);
                key.SetValue("ButtonText", "test1 options");
                key.SetValue("CLSID", "{9d5adece-24f0-4114-9da8-34c4c77a03eb}");
                key.SetValue("ClsidExtension", guid);
                key.SetValue("Icon", "");
                key.SetValue("HotIcon", "");
                key.SetValue("Default Visible", "Yes");
                key.SetValue("MenuText", "&test1 options2");
                key.SetValue("ToolTip", "test1 options");
                //key.SetValue("KeyPath", "no");
                registryKey.Close();
                key.Close();
            }
        }

        [ComUnregisterFunction]
        public static void UnregisterBHO(Type type)
        {
            string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");
            // BHO
            {
                RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegBHO, true);
                if (registryKey != null)
                    registryKey.DeleteSubKey(guid, false);
            }
            // Command
            {
                RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegCmd, true);
                if (registryKey != null)
                    registryKey.DeleteSubKey(guid, false);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Build Events**

Under project properties-->build events-->post-build event command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" /u "$(TargetName)"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" /f /i "$(TargetPath)"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /unregister /codebase "$(TargetPath)"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /codebase "$(TargetPath)"
```

**Debug tab**

Under project properties--> Debug -->Start external program and set it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`

and under `Command line arguments` set it to http://www.google.com

> You can download source project [from here](https://gofile.io/?c=2SKKR2), Password: `Aa123456!`

Comment: I tried to test the sample project but it shows me a certificate-related error. It said the certificate has a password and I don't have a password to use it. Other than that I noticed that in IEAddon.cs you are creating objects for the IE document. There is window.execScript(). If you just want to confirm then you can try to write an alert in it. It can help to print msg.

Comment: password: `Aa123456!`

Comment: does the approach to print the msg using window.execScript() worked? still, it is showing error in dll after providing the password.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I succeded to see `MessageBox` message when I wrote it inside `RegisterBHO` function

Comment: So it proves that your extension is working. right? Let me know, so that I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT but inside `GetSite/SetSite` functions it doesn't show the message

Comment: It needs an object to interact with the window or page which is not not available in Getsite/Setsite functions.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT How to make the browser invoke `GetSite/SetSite`

Comment: I will try to test and let you know about the changes in code.