# Begin download event internet explorer addon

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, add-on, bho

In my internet explorer add-on I want to detect when user begin to download a file, I with [FileDownload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/shdocvw.internetexplorer?view=dynamics-usd-3) event but it doesn;t fire when user downloads file but when navigating.

For illostating the secenario I created a small console app (If you want to test it on your computer):

1. Add reference to `SHDocVw` dll (location at `C:\Windows\System32`)
2. Create console app with code below
3. Enable yor app to interact with Internet explorer as I wrote bellow.

**The code:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
        object Empty = 0;
        object URL = "http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf";
        IE.BeforeNavigate2 += WebBrowser_BeforeNavigate21;
        IE.FileDownload += IE_FileDownload;
        IE.Visible = true;
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
        IE.Quit();
    }

    public void OnBeforeNavigate2(object sender, ref object URL,
                                      ref object Flags, ref object Target,
                                      ref object PostData, ref object Headers,
                                      ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BeforeNavigate2 fired!");
    }

    private static void IE_FileDownload(bool ActiveDocument, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{ActiveDocument} {DateTime.Now}");
        Cancel = true;

    }
```

**Enable IE to interact with app:**

1.1 In inernet explorer open "Internet Options"
   1.2 UnCheck the marked checkboxes under "Advance" tab

[image]

Comment: Is there any error when you debug the project? I found that you have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248843/hello-world-internet-explorer-extension-add-on) before. Is that the same project? I also find [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download) using javascript to detect the file download. If possible you could also give it a try.

Comment: @YuZhou No errors, if so I would say. The linked solusion assuming I have access to server side code, that's not the same case with extensions.

Comment: I saw you asked several similar questions and I answered the other one also. You could check my answer of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372634/detect-file-download-with-internet-explorer) and take it into consideration. I also suggest that you can focus on one thread as the similar threads will confuse us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with [BeforeNavigate2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v%3Dvs.85)) event like:

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
IE.BeforeNavigate2 += IE_BeforeNavigate2;
```

when user download file the following method invoked:

```
static void IE_BeforeNavigate2(object pDisp, ref object URL, 
ref object Flags, ref object TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, 
ref object Headers, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Event: IE_BeforeNavigate2");
}
```