# IE opening new tab about:blank instead of Webpage

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, bho

I am developing a BHO for IE in C# that controls the navigation flow of IE by checking the URL in onBeforeNavigateEvent.

Everything works fine except that when a link is opened in a new tab then some of the tabs opened as About:Blank.

I have checked the logs and also debugged the BHO no exception is thrown. However in the case of About:Blank BHO is initiated SetSite and GetSite methods are called but navigation event is not fired.

Also it happens when links are opened in new tab rapidly.

For testing purpose I disabled the addon and IE worked fine i.e. no About:Blank page.

Loading time of BHO is 0.1s and Navigation time is 0.5s

So, what could be the issue ?

The source I followed to build this BHO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/how-to-get-started-with-developing-internet-explorer-extensions)

Current Environment: IE 11,  Windows 10

Interop.cs

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace IE_BHO
{
    [
        ComImport(),
        ComVisible(true),
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
        Guid("FC4801A3-2BA9-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352")
    ]
    interface IObjectWithSite
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetSite([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object site);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSite(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr ppvSite);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct OLECMDTEXT
    {
        public uint cmdtextf;
        public uint cwActual;
        public uint cwBuf;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
        public char rgwz;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct OLECMD
    {
        public uint cmdID;
        public uint cmdf;
    }

    [ComImport(), ComVisible(true),
    Guid("B722BCCB-4E68-101B-A2BC-00AA00404770"),
    InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IOleCommandTarget
    {

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [PreserveSig]
        int QueryStatus(
            [In] IntPtr pguidCmdGroup,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint cCmds,
            [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref OLECMD prgCmds,
            //This parameter must be IntPtr, as it can be null
            [In, Out] IntPtr pCmdText);

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [PreserveSig]
        int Exec(
            //[In] ref Guid pguidCmdGroup,
            //have to be IntPtr, since null values are unacceptable
            //and null is used as default group!
            [In] IntPtr pguidCmdGroup,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint nCmdID,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint nCmdexecopt,
            [In] IntPtr pvaIn,
            [In, Out] IntPtr pvaOut);
    }

    [Guid("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA")]
    [InterfaceType(1)]
    public interface IServiceProvider
    {
        int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvObject);
    }

    [
        ComVisible(true),
        Guid("4C1D2E51-018B-4A7C-8A07-618452573E42"),
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)
    ]
    public interface IExtension
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        string ActivateEndPoint(string licenseKey, string userAgent);
    }
}
```

BHO.cs

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using SHDocVw;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Expando;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using mshtml;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace IE_BHO
{
    [
        SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode),
        ComVisible(true),
        Guid("BDCB9FDA-8370-40D9-96C9-9D4B4C25C0D8"),
        ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
        ProgId("myExtension"),
        ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IExtension))
    ]
    public class BHO : IObjectWithSite, IOleCommandTarget, IExtension
    {
        object _site;
        IWebBrowser2 _webBrowser2;

        #region Implementation of IObjectWithSite
        int IObjectWithSite.SetSite(object site)
        {
            _site = site;

            if (site != null)
            {
                var serviceProv = (IServiceProvider)_site;
                var guidIWebBrowserApp = Marshal.GenerateGuidForType(typeof(IWebBrowserApp));
                var guidIWebBrowser2 = Marshal.GenerateGuidForType(typeof(IWebBrowser2));

                IntPtr intPtr;
                serviceProv.QueryService(ref guidIWebBrowserApp, ref guidIWebBrowser2, out intPtr);

                _webBrowser2 = (IWebBrowser2)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(intPtr);

                ((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)_webBrowser2).BeforeNavigate2 += OnBeforeNavigate2;
                ((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)_webBrowser2).BeforeScriptExecute += S2_BeforeScriptExecute;
                ((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)_webBrowser2).DownloadComplete += BHO_DownloadComplete;                  
            }
            else
            {
                ((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)_webBrowser2).BeforeNavigate2 -= OnBeforeNavigate2;
                ((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)_webBrowser2).BeforeScriptExecute -= S2_BeforeScriptExecute;
                ((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)_webBrowser2).DownloadComplete -= BHO_DownloadComplete;

                _webBrowser2 = null;
            }                

            return 0;
        }

        int IObjectWithSite.GetSite(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr ppvSite)
        {
            IntPtr punk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(_webBrowser2);
            int hr = Marshal.QueryInterface(punk, ref guid, out ppvSite);
            Marshal.Release(punk);
            return hr;
        }

        public void OnBeforeNavigate2(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object Flags, ref object TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, ref object Headers, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            try
            {
                UrlObj dto = UrlManager.CheckUrl(URL.ToString());

                if (dto.IsInList)
                {
                     Cancel = true;
                     _webBrowser2.Navigate2("www.google.com");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        private void S2_BeforeScriptExecute(object pDispWindow)
        {
            ExposeMethodstoJS();
        }

        private void BHO_DownloadComplete()
        {
            ExposeMethodstoJS();
        }

        private void ExposeMethodstoJS(string calledBy)
        {
            try
            {
                HTMLDocument doc = _webBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument;

                if (doc != null)
                {
                    IHTMLWindow2 tmpWindow = doc.parentWindow;
                    dynamic window = tmpWindow;
                    IExpando windowEx = (IExpando)window;
                    PropertyInfo p = windowEx.AddProperty("myExtension");
                    p.SetValue(windowEx, this);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        #endregion


        #region Implementation of IOleCommandTarget
        int IOleCommandTarget.QueryStatus(IntPtr pguidCmdGroup, uint cCmds, ref OLECMD prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int IOleCommandTarget.Exec(IntPtr pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Implementation of IExtension 
        string IExtension.GetDetails()
        {
            return "Methods Exposed";
        }
        #endregion


        #region COMRegistration
        [ComRegisterFunction]
        public static void RegisterBHO(Type type)
        {
            RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects");
            RegistryKey guidKey = registryKey.CreateSubKey(type.GUID.ToString("B"));

            registryKey.Close();
            guidKey.Close();
        }

        [ComUnregisterFunction]
        public static void UnregisterBHO(Type type)
        {
            RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects", true);

            string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");

            if (registryKey != null)
            {
                registryKey.DeleteSubKey(guid, false);
            }
        }
        #endregion COMRegistration
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "myUrl" in your codes? And why are you using "Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider", which has "QueryService" function instead of "System.IServiceProvider"? The reason I ask is because "Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop" belongs to VS SDK, which is not related to IE BHO.

Comment: It would be much helpful if you could provide a minimal reproduceable example project. Feel free to remove all the sensitive information inside of your example project

Comment: myUrl is just a simple Url like 'google.com'

Comment: I have updated the question @ElvisXia-MSFT and has added the code

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE and OS are you using?

I think the issue occurs because the new tab is opened and navigated at almost the same time. For the detailed information, you could refer to [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2907806/blank-webpage-is-displayed-when-you-open-a-link-in-a-new-tab-in-intern).

You could also try the resolution in the article: Install the most recent cumulative security update for Internet Explorer.

Comment: I have edited my question to add Environment information

Comment: Also it happens not only on my machine but also on client machines

Comment: I suggest you to provide enough related code which can [reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So that we can test it in IE and try to help. If it's complex to reproduce, you could go to [this site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/support/) to open an assisted support or a virtual agent support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll discuss the issue with senior engineers and come back to you if there's any progress. Thank you for your understanding.