# RE - IE Crashing when exposing Methods for JS (Especially on VMs)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I am developing a BHO for IE in C#. The issue I am stuck in is that IE crashes by saying that

```
"Internet Explorer has stopped working"
```

then

```
"A problem with the webpage caused Internet Explorer to close and open the tab again"
```

This behavior is observed on Windows 10 (IE11) when used as a Virtual Machine.
However, the same BHO works fine on physical machines and also on Windows 8.1 (IE11) both Physical and Virtual Machine.

This usually occurs on navigating to a link in the already opened tab or on refreshing the page.

I have checked through logs it occurs when exposing methods for JS through BeforeScriptExecute event on this line p.SetValue(windowEx, this);

```
private void S2_BeforeScriptExecute(object pDispWindow)
{
    try
    {
        HTMLDocument doc = _webBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument;

        if (doc != null)
        {
            IHTMLWindow2 tmpWindow = doc.parentWindow;
            dynamic window = tmpWindow;
            IExpando windowEx = (IExpando)window;
            PropertyInfo p = windowEx.AddProperty("myExtension");
            p.SetValue(windowEx, this);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

The complete code is shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709619/ie-opening-new-tab-aboutblank-instead-of-webpage?noredirect=1#comment111100865_62709619) in the question.

Comment: I found that you have asked a [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62829660/ie-crashing-when-exposing-methods-for-js) before. I suggest that you can focus on one thread and delete the duplicate one so that it won't confuse us. Besides, I suggest that you can test on a real Windows 10 machine to see if the issue still persists.

Comment: @YuZhou I have tested it on physical machines and it works fine there.

Comment: If it works fine in physical machines then I think it should be no problem with your BHO. Maybe there're some environment settings different from the real environment. I think the test results in physical machines are more accurate than that in VM.